# Unity: Raycast not detecting parent object's tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm attempting to detect when a player wants to open/close a door so I create an *emptyObject* called **Door Hinge** that has the tag **"Door"**. I then created a *cube* object named **Door Body** which is a child of **Door Hinge** and gave it no tag but did give it a layer of **Ignore Raycast**. I have the scaling of the parent set to (1, 1, 1) but did change the scaling of the child as well as its x position slightly.

I'm not sure why but the raycast seems to only be detecting the child cube and not the parent empty object. Could anyone let me know if I'm missing anything or doing something wrong? I'll add my detection code for this below.

```
void CheckInteraction()
{
    // origin starts from the camera
    Vector3 origin = cam.transform.position;
    // direction of the camera
    Vector3 direction = cam.transform.forward;
    // The distance for the raycast
    float distance = 4f;
    // Used to store info about the object that the raycast hits
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(origin, direction, out hit, distance))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.tag);
        if (hit.transform.tag == "Door")
        {
            Debug.Log("HIT");
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<DoorOpen>().enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your parent gameobject have a collider?

Comment: Nope...I feel stupid now lol I'm still new to Unity and this was my first attempt with Raycasting. Thanks for that comment, that's what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I was missing was that the parent empty object needed to have a box collider added to it.